# Google Finance / Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I have been trying to get Net Assets and 1 Week Return for SPY on Google Spreadsheets but keep ending up with #N/A.

I have been following the information from this sheet but have yet to figure out what I am doing wrong: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

My Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kuAhDjzZT845s0tfAMM8s85ZUkONKF_7qlAX2JKW4yA/edit?usp=sharing

Have the codes for Google Finance stopped working or am I writing the codes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula works fine:

```
=googlefinance("spy", "price")
```

There are some attributes that are not available for some stocks, this could the the case for SPY.